# How to use Django rest framework to serve Media directory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to design an API that serves all the files in my django media directory in response to a GET request-- what should my app's view.py look like?

Comment: When you say serves all the files, do you mean serve back a list of filenames contained in the media directory? Or do you mean serve back binary data for a specific file when a filename is supplied?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileUploadParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) which Parses raw file upload content. The `request.data` property will be a dictionary with a single key 'file' containing the uploaded file.

```
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        save_location = open(MEDIA_ROOT + file_obj.name, 'wb+')
        for chunk in up_file.chunks():
            save_location.write(chunk)
            save_location.close()
        return Response(status=204)
```

Comment: Thanks! How is up_file supposed to be defined?

Comment: Sorry @D_M I don't understand your question

Comment: Nevermind. @ahereza Your answer has helped me, but with another question I had.

However, in this question, I asked how to send files in my media directory to a client when the client makes a get request to my server.

Any ideas?

I believe that right now you have told me how to allow a client to upload a file to my server which I can save to my media directory.

Answer (score 0):

> **function base code**

```
ufile = MODEL_NAME.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
if ufile:
    uf = ufile[0]
    path = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    path1 = "http://" + path + settings.MEDIA_URL
    url = path1 + str(uf.file).replace("./", "")
    dd = {'file': url}
    return Response(dd)
else:
    return Response(message="no file")
```

Answer (score 0):

> IF UR USING serializers

```
#serializers.PY
class ProfileImageSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MODEL_NAME
        fields = ('FIELD1', 'FIELD2')

#views.py
class GetProfileImageViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileImageSerialiser

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        image = MODEL_NAME.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        return image
```